# How to change an int to a double in this while loop, C

Tags: c, if-statement, while-loop

I'm working with this code to calculate the square and cube of an input, and I added a third option to calculate the value divided by 2, so I had to change the result from an int to a double, but I don't think I did it right. Here's what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
// Function prototypes int Square(int value); int Cube(int value); 

int main () 
{ 
    /* variable definition: */  
    int intValue, menuSelect,Results;
    double doubleValue, Resultsb;
    intValue = 1;
    doubleValue = intValue;
    // While a positive number 
    while (intValue > 0)  {     
        printf ("Enter a positive Integer\n: "); 
        scanf("%d", &intValue);
        doubleValue=intValue;
        if (intValue > 0)  { 
            printf ("Enter 1 to calculate Square, 2 to Calculate Cube, 3 to Shrink 
                   value in half \n: "); 
            scanf("%d", &menuSelect); 
            if (menuSelect == 1)  { 
                // Call the Square Function 
                Results = Square(intValue); 
                printf("Square of %d is %d\n",intValue,Results); 
            } 
            else if (menuSelect == 2)  { 
                // Call the Cube function 
                Results = Cube(intValue); 
                printf("Cube of %d is %d\n",intValue,Results); 
            } 
            else if (menuSelect == 3) {
                Resultsb = Shrink(doubleValue);
                printf("%f shrunk in half is %f\n", doubleValue,Resultsb);
            }
            else  
                printf("Invalid menu item, only 1, 2 or 3 is accepted\n"); 
        }       
    }       
    return 0; 
} 
/* function returning the Square of a number */ 
int Square(int value) 
{ 
    return value*value; 
}   
/* function returning the Cube of a number */ 
int Cube(int value) 
{     return value*value*value; 
}
double Shrink(double value)
{   return value/2;
}
```

If anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong that would be amazing, thank you!

Comment: You don't need to convert the input to a double. It will be converted automatically when you call `Shrink()`, because the parameter is a double.

Comment: Why do you have the prototypes commented out? You also need a prototype for `Shrink()`.

Comment: You need a declaration (aka prototype) for `Shrink()` before `main()`.  Otherwise the behaviour of your program is undefined (early versions of C, since the compiler will assume at the call point that `Shrink()` returns `int` and handle it accordingly) or won't compile (recent versions of C).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a prototype for the function before you call it. Otherwise, the default return type is `int`. So put:

```
int Square(int value);
int Cube(int value); 
double Shrink(double value);
```

before `main()`, or move the function definitions to the top.

You also don't need the `doubleValue` variable. Passing `intValue` to the function will automatically convert it, based on the prototype.

Here's the working program.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
// Function prototypes
int Square(int value);
int Cube(int value); 
double Shrink(double value);

int main () 
{ 
    /* variable definition: */  
    int intValue, menuSelect,Results;
    double Resultsb;
    intValue = 1;
    // While a positive number 
    while (intValue > 0)  {     
        printf ("Enter a positive Integer\n: "); 
        scanf("%d", &intValue);
        if (intValue > 0)  { 
            printf ("Enter 1 to calculate Square, 2 to Calculate Cube, 3 to Shrink value in half \n: "); 
            scanf("%d", &menuSelect); 

            if (menuSelect == 1)  { 
                // Call the Square Function 
                Results = Square(intValue); 
                printf("Square of %d is %d\n",intValue,Results); 
            } 
            else if (menuSelect == 2)  { 
                // Call the Cube function 
                Results = Cube(intValue); 
                printf("Cube of %d is %d\n",intValue,Results); 
            } 
            else if (menuSelect == 3) {
                Resultsb = Shrink(intValue);
                printf("%d shrunk in half is %f\n", intValue,Resultsb);
            }
            else  
                printf("Invalid menu item, only 1, 2 or 3 is accepted\n"); 
        }       
    }       
    return 0; 
} 
/* function returning the Square of a number */ 
int Square(int value) 
{ 
    return value*value; 
}   
/* function returning the Cube of a number */ 
int Cube(int value) 
{     return value*value*value; 
}
double Shrink(double value)
{   return value/2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As posted, your program does not compile because you omitted the protoptype for `Shrink()`.

- When it compiles the line `Resultsb = Shrink(doubleValue);`, the compiler infers that `Shrink` takes a `double` argument and returns an `int` (yes, it does that!).
- When it later gets to the definition of `Shrink()`, the actual definition is incompatible with the previous inferred prototype.

You should move your functions before the `main()` function or at least provide proper prototypes for them.

In modern C (C99 and later), you must define all functions or provide prototypes for them **before** you call them.  The above behavior applies to old style C, which is still supported by many compilers out there.